# sql, search for towns in radius of 22

Tags: mysql, minecraft

Just a quick question.

I'm creating a minimap and I only need towns (from towns table) that are 22 fields away. I have int x and y for each town and I use them to determine where the town is.

First that get on my mind was to use WHERE x < 56 and x > 34 ... but I don't know dose sql have that option so i wanted to ask how would I get only the towns 22 fields away.

Query:

```
'SELECT (id,x,y) 
FROM towns 
WHERE x >= \''.($x-22).'\' 
AND x <= \''.($x+22).'\' 
AND y >= \''.($y-22).'\' 
AND y <= \''.($y+22).'\''
```

Error is:
the error is **Warning**: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in –

Comment: x and y are ints, each combination of x and y presents 1 field. mah value for them is 1000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely use:

```
WHERE x < 56 AND x > 34
```

There's also `BETWEEN`:

```
WHERE x BETWEEN 35 AND 55
```

`BETWEEN` is inclusive, so equivalent to >= AND <=

Comment: that's not a radius, though. that's "within a square area".

Comment: OP asks if SQL supports that `WHERE` criteria, it does. Perhaps question is unclear.

Comment: I though sql didn't had many basic options, but apparently it does

Comment: now I have another problem, my query isn't working. does someone know why?

Comment: Add your full query and any error message to your question and we'll hammer it out.

Comment: 'SELECT (id,x,y) FROM towns WHERE x >= \''.($x-22).'\' AND x <= \''.($x+22).'\' AND y >= \''.($y-22).'\' AND y <= \''.($y+22).'\''

Comment: the error is <b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in

Comment: I tried BETWEEN ... AND ... first, but after that I write AND BETWEEN ... AND and I don't think it allows me to do that. it gives me the same error

Comment: Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: apparently I can't write (id,x,y) with (). it works now. but from some reason it isn't displaying all of them, although all towns are in 22 fields range

Comment: nwm I was clicking at the corner of the map. the other towns were on the other side

Answer (score 1):

`(here_x-there_x)*(here_x-there_x) + (here_y-there_y)*(here_y-there_y) < 22*22`

Pythagoras to the rescue!

Comment: I didn't actually mean radius as a circle, but as a square. but thanks anyway